# Reset max inactive interval - tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat, websocket, session-timeout

I am using `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);` to set maximum inactive interval. I used `60` just to test my setup , And this worked if user is inactive (*No http request*).

However, we are using websockets to communicate with server.

Client is sending a keepAlive ping every 20 seconds but unfortunately server is not recognizing this as activity and session is getting invalidated after 60 seconds.

What i am trying is to reset the inactive interval on every ping and for that i tried this -

`req.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);`

This didn't work. Is their any way to do it ?

Comment: Are you able to access user specific data from session ? if yes, it should work and should not get timeout..also chk is client pass jsessionid as parameter

Comment: @niiraj874u Yes, i am able to access data from session.

Comment: I have a similar problem with an applet. It sends requests but the session expires anyway. Maybe this property helps you **org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION**, take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html. No luck for me.

Comment: If you did not found a solution, maybe this can help. My problem was a framework (icefaces) invalidating the session when it own pages are not requested.